# Protecting Chromecast Receiver application

Tags: chromecast

We need to protect our HTML5/JS application from been stolen. (We need to protect JavaScript code mainly.)

Chromecast requires application hosted on HTTPS server. But anyone who puts sniffer on the same network with Chromecast can find what URL it loads and load it directly from any browser.

User agent etc. can be easily mimicked if use it to secure application.

What would be the best mechanism to protect proprietary JavaScript code in published Chromecast JavaScript application from been stolen?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Sasha

Answer (score 1):

One common practice is to minify + obfuscate the JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

Can generate some URL with a session id in it, and have the URL become invalid after some time. This way if someone intercept the URL using sniffer it will only work for a short period of time.

One other option is have your HTTP server whitelist the client IP adress or mac adress.

You might want to look at how the Spotify chrome app work.